# Is it possible to include a block of XAML in another block of XAML?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have XAML that looks like this:

```xml
<Grid VerticalOptions="Start">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Exclude Hidden" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
   <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="All cards except those tagged as hidden" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
   <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Include Hidden" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
   <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="All cards including those tagged as hidden" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
   <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Favorites" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
   <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Only cards tagged as favorites" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
   <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Hidden" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
   <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Only those cards tagged as hidden" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
</Grid>
```

The code appears on two pages.  I would like to leave it as XAML.

Is there a way that I can put this XAML into a file and include it in the other XAML's for each of the two pages. Note that I don't want to convert everything to C# as I have many instances like this.

Comment: https://blog.falafel.com/creating-reusable-xaml-user-controls-xamarin-forms/

Comment: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-user-control/

Comment: I agree with other comments, making a custom XAML control and reuse that xaml code will be best solution for your issue.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Create a directory called Templates, and then create a new View class, `MyCustomGrid` like so:

*Templates/MyCustomGrid.xaml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="MyProject.Templates.MyCustomGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Exclude Hidden" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="All cards except those tagged as hidden" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Include Hidden" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="All cards including those tagged as hidden" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Favorites" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Only cards tagged as favorites" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Hidden" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Only those cards tagged as hidden" Style="{StaticResource helpDetail}" />
</Grid>
```

*Templates/MyCustomGrid.xaml.cs*

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyProject.Templates
{
    public partial class MyCustomGrid : Grid
    {
        public MyCustomGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

To use it in another page, ie *MyPage.xaml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:templates="clr-namespace:MyProject.Templates;assembly=MyProject"
    x:Class="MyProject.MyPage">

    <templates:MyCustomGrid />

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: How can I pass data to the template from the page which includes it?

Comment: @Giorgi Do you try using viewBags?

Answer (score 3):

Insert the code in a ContentView. Call this code in both the ContentPages.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87415/how-to-display-content-from-one-xaml-inside-another

Comment: Can you supply an example for this rather than a link?  Thanks

Comment: @user2557859: Which example are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

In this case/dilemma, you can leverage Xamarin's ContentView class.

You can think of ContentView as a sub-class or child of a ContentPage. So, basically, if you have a Xamarin page that is a ContentPage. And a ContentView can be a view or sub-element within a ContentPage. Both of them can have their own structure:

A ContentPage XAML (ex. MainContentPage.xaml)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage>
       <ContentPage.Content>
          <StackLayout x:Name="MainLayout">
          ...
          </StackLayout>
       </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

A ContentView XAML  (ex. ChildContentView.xaml)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentView>
       <ContentView.Content>
          <StackLayout>
          ...
          </StackLayout>
       </ContentView.Content>
    </ContentView>
```

And the ContentPage class (ex. MainContentPage.cs) would look possibly like this:

```
 namespace Your.Package
 {
      public class MainContentPage : ContentPage
      {
          public MainContentPage()
          {
              //Some code here, binding, initialization etc.

              //Create an object of the ChildContentView code behind/class
              ChildContentView childView = new ChildContentView();

              //Add the childView to the MainLayout of the ContentPage
              this.MainLayout.Children.Add(childView);

              InitializeComponent();
          }
      }
 }
```

And in your ChildContentView.cs (code behind) you can basically do the same coding as what you can do in the code behind of any ContentPage class. You can add StackLayout, you can do binding, and you can use other inherited methods from the TemplatedView parent class. See [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ContentView/) for more information.