# How to reuse XAML blocks and define function-like blocks?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have two XAML-related questions related to code reuse - basically I'm trying to define SVG-like graphics for my controls in a generic, [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) fashion. So...

**(1) How to define and insert a block?**

I have the following piece of XAML code which I'd like to insert in different places:

```xml
<PathGeometry Figures="M 585.34928 1465.3307 ... z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
```

How can I define such a reusable piece of code, so that I can insert it for example here:

```xml
<Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Path.Data>
        <!-- How to change the line below so that the predefined block is used? -->
        <PathGeometry Figures="M 585.34928 1465.3307 ... z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

**(2) How to define whole blocks behaving like functions functions in XAML?**

I have the following piece of XAML code which I'd like to insert in different places, but with different value of `Fill` parameter:

```xml
<!-- How to make the following block to behave like a function - so that I could insert such paths with different fill colors? -->
<Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Fill="???">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry Figures="M 585.34928 1465.3307 ... z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

---

I tried to tackle both problems using an approach presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48055087/is-it-possible-to-include-a-block-of-xaml-in-another-block-of-xaml/48543742), but unfortunately [`Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.path?view=netcore-3.1) and [`PathGeometry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.pathgeometry?view=netcore-3.1) classes are sealed.

Comment: use static resources something like `<Application.Resources><PathGeometry x:Key="xxx"....` and then `<Path Data="{StaticResource xxx}" ...`

Comment: Thanks! That answered my first question in this particular context :)